# Is it possible to define a generic type which is a tuple struct holding an enum?

Tags: rust, enums

I am trying to implement TypeState + Builder pattern for my struct `IDCardNumber`.

```
use std::phantom::PhantomData;

struct IDPrefix(IDPrefixEnum);

enum IDPrefixEnum {
    A
    B
}
// `IDSuffixEnum` and `IDSuffix` ommitted but follow identical structure to that of 'Prefix'.

struct IDCardNumber<P, S, V> {
    prefix: P,
    suffix: S,
    digits: Vec<u8>,
    v: PhantomData<V>,
}
```

My question is: is it possible to hold an enum in the tuple of a tuple struct? If yes, how can I match on the enum?

Comment: Not just this is possible, it is also a common idiom when you want the type to be public but the enum variants to be private (or hide the fact that you use an enum).

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: is it possible to hold an enum in the tuple of a tuple struct?

Why wouldn't it?

> If yes, how can I match on the enum?

The normal way?

```rust
match thing {
    IDPrefix(IDPrefixEnum::A) => ...,
    IDPRefix(IDPrefixEnum::B) => ...,
}
```

You could also use a [guard](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/match/guard.html), or borrow the enum out of the struct and match on that "directly".

Comment: Thanks, just couldn't find any resource on google illustrating this.

Comment: I don't think there's any specific resources on the subject because it's just the composition (nesting) of patterns, it's not a specific feature, and is fundamentally no different than e.g. `match thing { Some(0) => ..., Some(n) => ..., None => ... }`  or other such patterns.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, yes, you can hold an enum in a tuple struct. You can match like this, for example:

```rust
struct IDPrefix(IDPrefixEnum);

enum IDPrefixEnum {
    A,
    B,
}

fn main() {
    let id = IDPrefix(IDPrefixEnum::A);
    
    match id {
        IDPrefix(IDPrefixEnum::A) => println!("yehy!"),
        IDPrefix(IDPrefixEnum::B) => println!("no!"),
    }
    
    match id.0 {
        IDPrefixEnum::A => println!("yehy!"),
        IDPrefixEnum::B => println!("no!"),
    }
}
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2a3b157c08f8f66afb0af2e2328a02d5)

**Stdout:**

```
yehy!
yehy!
```